# Plotting precision@k and recall@k in ROCR (R)

Tags: r, plot, classification, data-visualization, precision-recall

I'm evaluating a binary classifier in R with the ROCR package. My classifier outputs a score between 0 and 1 for target 0/1 labels.

I'd like to plot precision and recall @ k but can't find a way to do it. Calling `performance()` without specifying the x-axis measure plots the precision value by score cutoff:

```
library(ROCR)
#df <- a two-dimensional dataframe with prediction scores and actual labels of my classifier 
pred <- prediction(df$score, df$label)
pr_curve <- performance(pred, measure="prec")
```

For precision (or recall) at k, I'd need to plot the precision against the rank of each prediction, ordered by descending score:

```
pred <- prediction(df$score, df$label)
pr_curve <- performance(pred, measure="prec", x.measure="rank") #but there seems to be no "rank" in ROCR!
```

Is there a way to do this in ROCR? I'm open to use alternative libraries if this isn't the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load libraries and define train and test set:

```
library(mlbench)
library(e1071)
library(ROCR)
data(BreastCancer)
df = BreastCancer
idx = sample(1:nrow(df),150)
trn = df[idx,]
test = df[-idx,]
```

Fit naives bayes

```
fit = naiveBayes(Class ~ .,data=trn)
```

In the manual for performance, it is written,

> Precision/recall graphs: measure="prec", x.measure="rec".

Plot precision-recall:

```
pred = prediction(predict(fit,test,type="raw")[,2],test$Class)
#plot to see it is working correctly:
plot(performance(pred,measure="prec",x.measure="rec"))
```

[image]

Now for your case to do it at K, we can also do the precision recall from scratch:

```
#combine prob, predicted labels, and actual labels
res = data.frame(prob=predict(fit,test,type="raw")[,2],
predicted_label=predict(fit,test),
label = test$Class)
res = res[order(res$prob,decreasing=TRUE),]
res$rank = 1:nrow(res)
# calculate recall, which is the number of actual classes we get back
res$recall = cumsum(res$label=="malignant")/sum(res$label=="malignant")
# precision, number of malignant cases we predicted correctly
res$precision = cumsum(res$label=="malignant")/res$rank

# check the two plots
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(performance(pred,measure="prec",x.measure="rec"))
plot(res$recall,res$precision,type="l")
```

[image]

Now you have it correct, getting or plotting precision at K is simply:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
with(res,
plot(rank,precision,main="self-calculated",type="l"))
plot(pred@n.pos.pred[[1]],
pred@tp[[1]]/(pred@fp[[1]]+pred@tp[[1]]),
type="l",main="from RORC")
```

I am not aware of a way to use the .plot.performance function.. But you can use the variables stored under prediction object. pred@tp is the true positive, pred@fp is the false positive, so tp / fp+fp gives precision and pred@n.pos.pred gives the rank essentially.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works. Are we essentially saying that the only way to do this is by manually calculating precision, recall, and rank? This solution doesn't really use ROCR, nor any library. The problem is that in this way we'd also need to re-implement by hand all the calculations across several cross-validations runs (i.e., average precision at k). It may be cumbersome.

Comment: @st1led, It's a few lines of code, and you need to know it's correct right? I edited my answer to include how u can use the prediction object to plot what you need

Comment: Got it. `pred@n.pos.pred` is what I was looking for!